# Error "Missing $ inserted" but i cant find where they should be

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have an error where he tells me I have 4 missing $ in one line (paragraph below) but I don't know where. Everywhere I used _ or ^ is surrounded by $ and I can't find the missing ones. The log also says there are missing $ in completely empty lines and there are no $ left open... please help, i'm crying.
Also if I replace the ^ with \textsuperscript{} the error doesn't go away either... Maybe I'm blind and missing something but I don't think so...

```
Unter dem Abzug wurden die benötigte Massen an Natriumsdiulfit und
Kaliumiodat abgewogen und in VE-Wasser gelöst. Erhalten wurden eine
15,0mmol\cdot\text{mL} $^{-1}$ Hydrogensulfit-Lösung und eine 20,0
mmol\cdot \text{L} $^{-1}$ Kaliumiodat-Lösung. Der Kolben, der die
Hydrogensulfit-Lösung enthielt wurde im Thermostat auf 25°C
erhitzt. Die Volumina an VE-Wasser, Stärke und Hydrogensulfit wurden
gemäß Tabelle 1 in das Reaktionsgefäß pipettiert. Das pipettierte
Iodat wurde in ein Becherglas gegeben, welches in das Wasserbad des
Thermostats gehalten wurde, bis es 25°C erreichte. Der Magnetrührer
unter dem Reaktionsgefäß befand sich vor der Zugabe des Iodats unter
einem Drittel des Maximalwerts. Als auch die Lösung innerhalb des
Reaktionsgefäß mit Hilfe des Thermometers auf 25°C geprüft wurde,
wurde das Iodat im Becherglas rasch in das Reaktionsgefäß gekippt. Das
Reaktionsgefäß wurde nach diesem Vorgang verschlossen und der
Magnetrührer auf ein Drittel der Maximalleistung gestellt. Zum selben
Zeitpunkt, in dem das Iodat in das Reaktionsgefäß gekippt wurde, wurde
die Stoppuhr gestartet. Sobald der Farbumschlag im Reaktionsgefäß zu
sehen war, wurde die Zeit gestoppt. Dieser Vorgang wurde vier mal für
die erste Mischung und drei mal für dei zweite Mischung durchgeführt.
```

Comment: I think \cdot should be in mathmode as well, so having $\cdot \text{L}^{-1}$ would be more appropriate, \text working in mathmode too

Comment: the error message you have not shown shows the exact point of the error, `\cdot` must be in math mode. You may want to look at the `siunitx` package.

Comment: The `\cdot` is defined as `\mathchar"2201`. When luatex is used, then you needn't switch to math mode when printing this character.

Comment: Off-topic: Is "Natriumsdiulfit" spelled correctly? Should it maybe be "Natriumdisulfit"?

Answer (score 5):

TeX shows the exact location of the error in the message, the linebreak shows how far TeX had processed.

The document below produces the error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 15,0mmol\cdot
                 \text{mL} $^{-1}$ Hydrogensulfit-Lösung und eine 20,0
? h
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

?
```

highlighting `\cdot` which is a math mode command.

Changing those lines to

```
Unter dem Abzug wurden die benötigte Massen an Natriumsdiulfit und
Kaliumiodat abgewogen und in VE-Wasser gelöst. Erhalten wurden eine
$15,0\text{mmol}\cdot\text{mL}^{-1}$ Hydrogensulfit-Lösung und eine
$20,0\text{mmol}\cdot \text{L}^{-1}$ Kaliumiodat-Lösung. Der Kolben, der die
```

will fix the error but you should look at the the `siunitx` package for a more consistent way of marking up units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

Unter dem Abzug wurden die benötigte Massen an Natriumsdiulfit und
Kaliumiodat abgewogen und in VE-Wasser gelöst. Erhalten wurden eine
15,0mmol\cdot\text{mL} $^{-1}$ Hydrogensulfit-Lösung und eine 20,0
mmol\cdot \text{L} $^{-1}$ Kaliumiodat-Lösung. Der Kolben, der die
Hydrogensulfit-Lösung enthielt wurde im Thermostat auf 25°C
erhitzt. Die Volumina an VE-Wasser, Stärke und Hydrogensulfit wurden
gemäß Tabelle 1 in das Reaktionsgefäß pipettiert. Das pipettierte
Iodat wurde in ein Becherglas gegeben, welches in das Wasserbad des
Thermostats gehalten wurde, bis es 25°C erreichte. Der Magnetrührer
unter dem Reaktionsgefäß befand sich vor der Zugabe des Iodats unter
einem Drittel des Maximalwerts. Als auch die Lösung innerhalb des
Reaktionsgefäß mit Hilfe des Thermometers auf 25°C geprüft wurde,
wurde das Iodat im Becherglas rasch in das Reaktionsgefäß gekippt. Das
Reaktionsgefäß wurde nach diesem Vorgang verschlossen und der
Magnetrührer auf ein Drittel der Maximalleistung gestellt. Zum selben
Zeitpunkt, in dem das Iodat in das Reaktionsgefäß gekippt wurde, wurde
die Stoppuhr gestartet. Sobald der Farbumschlag im Reaktionsgefäß zu
sehen war, wurde die Zeit gestoppt. Dieser Vorgang wurde vier mal für
die erste Mischung und drei mal für dei zweite Mischung durchgeführt.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You also closed up some spaces before `^{-1}` but didn't mention it in your prose.  (Yes, i know: covered by `siunitx`, but still ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton it's (now) math mode so spaces are ignored anyway, I just closed them up in the sourced as they looked odd.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely look into loading the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and employing its `\qty` and `\unit` macros to typeset scientific units and their associated units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasngerman{\hyphenation{ka-lium-iodat}}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} % use commas as decimal markers

\begin{document}

Unter dem Abzug wurden die benötigte Massen an Natriumdisulfit und Kaliumiodat abgewogen und in VE-Wasser gelöst. Erhalten wurden eine 
%15,0mmol\cdot\text{mL} $^{-1}$ 
\qty[inter-unit-product=\cdot]{15,0}{\milli\mol \milli\liter\tothe{-1}} 
Hydrogensulfit-Lösung und eine 
%20,0 mmol\cdot \text{L} $^{-1}$ 
\qty{20,0}{\liter\tothe{-1}}
Kaliumiodat-Lösung. Der Kolben, der die Hydrogensulfit-Lösung enthielt wurde im Thermostat auf 
\qty{25}{\celsius} 
erhitzt. Die Volumina an VE-Wasser, Stärke und Hydrogensulfit wurden gemäß Tabelle 1 in das Reaktionsgefäß pipettiert. Das pipettierte Iodat \dots

\end{document}
```